# Is there anyway to add an object list of a class to another object list of another class that contains instance of the first class as it's attribute?

Tags: c#, list

I have a list of objects of Category class.

I have another list of objects of MarketData class which contains instances of Category class as it's attributes.

MarketData Class:

```
    class MarketData
    {
        private int id;
        private Category business;
        private Category location;
        private string companyName;
        private string mobileNum;
        private string email;
     }
```

How can I add list of Category class objects to the list of MarketData in a single line without using foreach loop?

foreach loop method that I don't want:

```
List<MarketData> marketDataList = new List<MarketData>();
List<Category> businessList = new List<Category>();

int i = 0;
foreach(Category item in businessList)
{

 marketDataList[i].Business = item;
 i++;
}
```

Comment: Post your code here and not as image links...

Comment: @shaze Does your list always contain the same amount of item and the order also always match ?

Comment: @Franck yes and yes

Comment: You need at least 1 loop that is certain. Are you looking for a solution without a loop or only a single liner is ok even if it contain a loop ?

Comment: I don't understand why you want to get rid of the foreach. I feel like other solutions are going to obscure the logic. If you're worried about lines of code, you can integrate the incrementation into the assignment statement: `marketDataList[i++].Business = item;`.

Answer (score 0):

Single line you can use [Enumerable.Range()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.range?view=netframework-4.8) to generate a collection of index and use that to loop and assign directly using `Linq`.

```
List<MarketData> marketDataList = new List<MarketData>();
List<Category> businessList = new List<Category>();

// this a one liner formatted on many line for visibility reasons
Enumerable.Range(0, marketDataList.Count()) // generate a collection from 0 to Count
                  .ToList() // as a list
                  .ForEach(i => marketDataList[i].Business = businessList[i]); // for each index assign the value
```